# Libreoffice writer closes at startup

Tags: libreoffice, gtk

Libreoffice Writer closes at startup, just after showing the blank page. I'm pretty sure it comes from an outdated extension (from the french spellchecker Antidote), but I can't uninstall it since LO won't stay open long enough.

I tried

```
libreoffice --writer
```

and it says:

```
 (soffice:3407): WARNING **: Couldn't register with accessibility bus: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote
 application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy
 blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network
 connection was broken. Unable to load library icui18n "Cannot load
 library icui18n: (icui18n: Ne peut ouvrir le fichier d'objet partagé:
 Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)" 

 (soffice:3407): Gtk-ERROR **: GTK+ 2.x symbols detected. Using GTK+
 2.x and GTK+ 3 in the same process is not supported


 Fatal exception: Signal 5 [...]
```

I uninstalled, purged and reinstalled the whole thing, by the way. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried starting from the terminal with the `--safe-mode` option?  If it's really an extension, you should be able to start LibreOffice, uninstall the extension (or reinstall), and be up and running again.

Comment: Note that this only works if you have 5.3 or later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
libreoffice writer --safe-mode
```

allowed me to disable the Antidote 8 extension (which was designed for LO 4). The problem is solved, thanks anonymous2.

So the Antidote 8 extension for LO isn't working anymore with LO 5... too bad.

Comment: Good to see it worked.